# Quicksorting a file of integers

Tags: java

I have to quicksort a user input file of integers(each line in the file contains one integer). My quicksort methods work, I tested them already. I am having trouble reading the file and printing it out in sorted order in the same file. I also have to time how long the process takes. Here is what I have so far: The first argument passed into the method is the number of integers the file will be and the second argument passed is the name of the file. The generateRandom() method is from Question0 class and it creates a file with random integers, each separated by a line. It takes two arguments an int and a filename. It creates a file with the name filename and it consists of int integers. Hopefully all this makes sense.

Edit: Here is a working code but I am having trouble running it when there are 1million numbers in the file. It gives outofmemory error. When there are 1billion, it says numberformatexception. I have to run a test file with 1billion numbers in it.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class QuickSort1000 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        String filePath = args[1];
        Question0 genRan = new Question0();
        genRan.generateRandom(n, filePath);
        //rest if for quicksorting
        File inFile = new File(filePath);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(inFile);
        int[] list = new int[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            list[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        in.close();

        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        qSort(list, 0, list.length - 1);
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long duration = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println("Total time: " + duration + " nanoseconds");
        for(int i = 1; i < list.length; i++)
        {
            if(list[i - 1] > list[i])
            {
                throw new Exception("Not in sorted order");
            }
            //System.out.print(list[i]);
        }

    }

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    /**
     * The main quicksort method that uses the partition method below
     * @param a the input array
     * @param p the first valid index of array
     * @param r the last valid index of array
     */
        public static void qSort(int[] a, int p, int r) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (p < r)
            {
                int q = Partition(a, p, r);
                qSort(a, p, q - 1);
                qSort(a, q + 1, r);
            }

        }
        /**
         * Partitions the array with respect to the last element in the array
         * @param a the input array
         * @param p the first element in the array
         * @param r the last element in the array
         * @return the element with which we will partition with respect to. The 
         * return element will be in its correct spot.
         */
        private static int Partition(int[] a,int p, int r)
        {
            int x = a[r];
            int i = p - 1;
            int temp = 0;
            for(int j = p; j <= r - 1; j++)
            {
                if(a[j] <= x)
                {
                    i++;
                    temp = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[j];
                    a[j] = temp;
                }
            }
             temp = a[i+1];
             a[i+1] = a[r];
             a[r] = temp;
             return i + 1;
        }


    }
```

Comment: What is your question? Is that code relevant to the _question_?

Comment: Still don't see a **question**, only a problem statement.

Comment: So, wait.  You're given a number (n), and a filename (f), and you're supposed to generate n random numbers, write them to f in a random order, read them from f, sort them, and write them _back_ to f in the correct order?  Is this homework?  Because I'm starting to feel like you read the question wrong.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan The question is just asking to time how long it takes to sort from a given file. Is it not possible to write out the sorted file? I just wanted to write out the sorted file for me as practice. I guess I will try to figure that out later. For now, I will focus on timing the whole process. When I run the code, it always says 0milliseconds. I am guessing the input file is not getting sorted. I guess the question is why am i getting 0 milliseconds?

Comment: @user3754524, Try increasing the size of the input, to let's say 1 million integers. I think with small inputs, it is actually taking less than 1 ms.

Comment: For one thing, currentTimeMillis() is unreliable, I would use getNanoTime() and do the necessary math conversions to milliseconds if you need to. Also I would check firstly that you have the right file, and secondly that the file has integer numbers in it separated by spaces, and as merlin says, you need a lot of them.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the following statement, I infer that the OP is asking how to perform `IO` on the same file for input and output.

> I am having trouble reading the file and printing it out in sorted
>   order in the same file.

1. You do not need to use `hasNext()` if the user is telling you exactly how many integers there are.
2. On a similar vein, there is no need to create a variable size `List` if you already know many integers there are.
3. You should not open a `PrintWriter` pointing at a file until you are ready to clobber it.

Here is a corrected version of `main` from your original question.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    String filePath = args[1];
    //rest is for the quicksorting
    File inFile = new File(filePath);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inFile);
    int[] list = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        list[i] = in.nextInt();
    in.close();
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    qSort(list, 0, list.length - 1);
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long duration = endTime - startTime;
    System.out.println(duration);


    // Create a PrintWriter and clobber the file AFTER you have read it.
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(filePath);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println(list[i]);
        out.println(list[i]);
    }
    out.close();

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you also close the scanner?

Comment: @PerryMonschau, Yes, fixing.